# Error: Magic RPC Error: [-32603] Internal error: Unsupported Magic Connect method. when using magic sdk for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, next.js13, magic-sdk

### The Problem:

The code bellow throws a `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Magic RPC Error: [-32603] Internal error: Unsupported Magic Connect method` and I cannot figure out why.

```
node version : 18.12.1
magic-sdk version: ^8.1.1
nextjs13
```

```
import { Magic } from 'magic-sdk';

const magic = new Magic(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

try {

        magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email });
    
        const didToken = await magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({
                    email,
                });
                console.log({ didToken });
                
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
    
        }
```

I have tried downgrading the `magic-sdk` version to `8.1.1`  with `node version` to `18.12.1` but the problem still persists

The expected behavior is for the code to send a `magic link` to the users email and the user should use that `magic link` to login into the application

Answer (score 0):

You probably might have created a "Magic Connect" app instead of a "Magic Auth" app.

Answer (score 0):

You did same mistake which I did.
[check this image : magic auth vs connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SHo7.png)

You should created a Magic Auth app instead of Magic Connect.

Once new app is created, new API key will be visible on the magic website. You can see all of yours apps in the Dashboard.
Replace the old API Key with the new one.
Restart your server.